# Android Studio Google Vision Barcode scanning in fragment Buttomviewer

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trapped in a problem. I tried to use Google Vision for barcode scanning. Now I wanted to integrate the whole thing into a ButtomView as an own fragment but everything remains dark. I don't get ERROR either.

I just want when I press on Home in this example the reader (camera) starts and I can scan barcode. 
If I open another tab, the scanning is stopped. I have add to activity_main.xml a framelayout and a buttomnavigationView

activity_main.xml

````
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/navigation"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Creat a fragment Layout with all necessary outlets.
fragment_scan.xml

````
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="640px"
            android:layout_height="480px"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/camera_view"/>

        <TextView
            android:text=" code reader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtContent"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Process"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgview"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>```
````

In the mainActivity.java I managed the different fragments to show and works fine. The surface view, imageViewand the txtConten.

Now the problem. The linking works good but everything which is linked to the layout is here but black.
scanfragment.java

````
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

public class scanfragment extends Fragment {

    TextView barcodeInfo;
    SurfaceView cameraView;
    CameraSource cameraSource;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View SCANVIEW = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);
        cameraView = (SurfaceView)  SCANVIEW.findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        barcodeInfo = (TextView) SCANVIEW.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);

        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector =
                new BarcodeDetector.Builder(container.getContext())
                        .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.CODE_128)//QR_CODE)
                        .build();
        cameraSource = new CameraSource
                .Builder(container.getContext(), barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
                .build();
        cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                try {
                    cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    Log.e("CAMERA SOURCE", ie.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });


        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {

                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

                if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                    barcodeInfo.post(new Runnable() {    // Use the post method of the TextView
                        public void run() {
                            barcodeInfo.setText(    // Update the TextView
                                    barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue
                            );
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan,container, false);
    } 
}```
````

I think the problem is the linking between the fragment and the variables.
In the tutorial everything is in the MainActivity and here in the fragment.
In the mainActivity it was linked like this:

```
BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector =
                new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                        .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.CODE_128)//QR_CODE)
                        .build();
        cameraSource = new CameraSource
                .Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
                .build();
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: It's hard to understand the specific question you're asking here, and you seem to have posted a lot of code. Are you able to edit your question to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Ideally remove the commented-out code, and fix typos (`ButtomView(er)`?) and simplify your example so it shows just the problem you're encountering and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);
```

with:

```
return SCANVIEW;
```